# discord.py on_member_update game activity

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to print the member's current activity (Game Playing)
but when I print `after.activity.name` it gives me my custom status

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    print(after.activity.name)
```

and printing `after.activity.type` gives me `ActivityType.custom`

when printing `after.activties` it prints:

```
(<CustomActivity name='808s & heartbreak' emoji=None>, <Activity type=<ActivityType.playing: 0> name='League of Legends' url=None details="Summoner's Rift (Normal)" application_id=401518684763586560 session_id=None emoji=None>)
```

Comment: Your code works, but a `Member.activity` does not only include the games playing, it also includes the custom activities, music he is listening to, streams, etc. And your function is triggered whenever there is a change in any `Member` from the server, not only in the activity, that is why you see your own status being triggered.

Comment: is there a way to only select `ActivityType.playing`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter activity whose type is not `playing`

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    game = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "playing"]
    if game:
        print(game[0].name)
```

Comment: thanks that worked. but i had to change it to `game = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]`